# Access 2013 Error 3219 Invalid Operation without Code change

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I use an Access 2013 DB front-end with SQL Server 2017 and all works fine for years now.
When I duplicate the frontend file with a copy, all is still fine.

However, when I duplicate the file and add new content and start it, one code section in a form crashes with `Error 3219`. That's strange because this section had no changes.

The crashing code is identical in the original and the copy, all forms, queries, tables and connections are identical. Debugging is clean. Original works, copy does not.

The code is an average SQL query with some joins which is added to the record source of the form.

```
SQL = " select …."
MyForm.recordsource = sql   <-- here we have the exception then
```

The SQL string works fine if executed as query and still works in the original file.

I did a reorganisation and compression on the new access file but still no change.
All other functions or the program work still fine so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: When does it crash?  What "new content" did you add?

Comment: This could happen for many reasons. First you should prove that all linked tables are still valid in this copy which fails.

Comment: Could be corruption. Comment out these two lines, then _rewrite_ them (no copy-paste).

Comment: All queries and tables are fine in the copy. they are used by a lot of functions and forms and wörk fine. "New Content" are new forms or modified old forms, but has no links or binding to the form which causes the Problem. This form and the Code and functions or data is still original. Rewrite the lines doesnt help. For me it looks like the query gets a timeout in the copy, but no timeout in the original. Datasource and amount of data are both the same SQL database.